# Merge large images with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, image, large-files, image-stitching

I am hoping someone can help me with merging several large images (PNG) into one. I have up to 30 images that are 20000x2000 and would like to merge them. The output is an image that can be loaded into GIS software.

The issue I am having is I am out of memory after about the 4th image.

The code I have below essentially holds the entire image in memory as it does the stitching. Is there any way to effectively stitch the images without loading it all into memory, or, increase the memory allowance and make use of all my RAM and/or virtual memory?

```
    Public Function stitchAllImagesOnXAxis(imageDirectoryPath As String, outputImagePath As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim evolvingImage As Bitmap
        Dim filenames() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(imageDirectoryPath)

        For i As Integer = 0 To filenames.Count - 1

            If Not filenames(i).EndsWith(".png") Then filenames = filenames.RemoveAt(i)

        Next i

        If filenames.Count = 0 Then Return False

        Dim FS As New IO.FileStream(filenames(0), IO.FileMode.Open)
        evolvingImage = Bitmap.FromStream(FS)
        FS.Close()



        For i As Integer = 1 To filenames.Count - 1

            FS = New IO.FileStream(filenames(i), IO.FileMode.Open)
            evolvingImage = stitchImagesOnXAxis(evolvingImage, Bitmap.FromStream(FS), 5)
            FS.Close()

        Next

        evolvingImage.Save(outputImagePath, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        evolvingImage.Dispose()

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
```

Comment: My idea of concatenating IDAT chunks from the various files seems to be invalid because, as far as I understand now, separate IDAT chunks are simply portions of one compressed block, not separately compressed blocks.

Comment: Yes I did give it a go, but it just made the software call it corrupted or invalid.

Comment: 1) I can create pngs with the IDAT chunks (or the data within) concatenated with no errors according to [pngcheck](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html, but they do not open properly. Did you remember to update the CRC for the IHDR after updating the image height? 2) You might have more chance of success if you use anything other than GDI+.

Comment: No I did not, I now have no error but the different idat chunks are acting like layers. My endstate is to georectify this as a tif.

Comment: I tried putting all the image data into one IDAT chunk (that needs another CRC recalculation, of course), because it *should* be possible to do that with DEFLATE-compressed data and again pngcheck says it's ok but IrfanView and Photoshop were not happy. It's possible your GIS s/w will interpret it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to solve this through the io.filestream class and insert the data as required. I successfully stitched up to 4gb of images together (roughly 40 images of 20000x2000) which will definitely be beyond my requirements.

Comment: Well done! It would be worth writing up your solution, with the essential code, as an answer to this question so that if someone else needs to do the same thing in the future they can find a working method. If you leave a comment letting me know you've done that, you'll get an upvote from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Public Function stitchAllImagesOnXAxisSO(imageDirectoryPath As String, outputImagePath As String, tolerance As Integer) As Boolean

    Try
        'blank 54 byte header for BMP
        Dim headerBytes() As Byte = blankHeader()

        'track the total width of the bmp for the header information
        Dim totalWidth As Integer = 0

        'the height of the BMP (assumes all images being joined are the same height)
        Dim height As Integer = 0

        'the files in the directory specified
        Dim filenames() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(imageDirectoryPath)

        'the filestream used to read each file
        Dim FS As IO.FileStream

        'a class to read the header information of the BMP files
        Dim dynamicHeaderInfo As BMPHeaderInformation

        'byte array to copy the bytes read to
        Dim copyBuffer() As Byte

        'ensure each file is a bmp file
        For i As Integer = 1 To filenames.Count - 1

            If Not filenames(i).EndsWith(".bmp") Then filenames = filenames.RemoveAt(i)

        Next i

        'if there isn't more than one image available then exit
        If filenames.Count < 2 Then Return False

        'if the output image exists than delete it
        If IO.File.Exists(outputImagePath) Then IO.File.Delete(outputImagePath)

        'and open it as new 
        Dim evolvingImageFS As New IO.FileStream(outputImagePath, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

        'write a blank header
        evolvingImageFS.Write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Length)

        'set the height of the overall image (all images assumed the same height)
        dynamicHeaderInfo = New BMPHeaderInformation(filenames(0))
        height = dynamicHeaderInfo.width

        'writing one row at a time from one image at a time

        For row As Integer = 0 To height - 1

            For i As Integer = 0 To filenames.Count - 1

                'get the header data
                dynamicHeaderInfo = New BMPHeaderInformation(filenames(i))

                'open the file
                FS = New IO.FileStream(filenames(i), IO.FileMode.Open)



                'each time we are looking at the first row of an image add that width to the overall width
                If row = 0 Then totalWidth += dynamicHeaderInfo.width

                'set the position of the stream
                FS.Position = dynamicHeaderInfo.headerLength + (row * dynamicHeaderInfo.width * 3) + (row * dynamicHeaderInfo.rowPaddingLength)

                'set up the byte array to read in the bytes
                ReDim copyBuffer((dynamicHeaderInfo.width * 3) - 1)
                FS.Read(copyBuffer, 0, dynamicHeaderInfo.width * 3)
                'write the bytes to the new stream
                evolvingImageFS.Write(copyBuffer, 0, dynamicHeaderInfo.width * 3)

                'if we are at the last image and the total width is less than 500, write the trailing zeros on the row
                If i = filenames.Count - 1 Then padRowFromStream(totalWidth, evolvingImageFS)

                'close the stream
                FS.Close()
                FS.Dispose()

            Next

        Next

        'set the new header information
        setNewWidth(totalWidth, evolvingImageFS)
        setNewheight(height, evolvingImageFS)
        setNewImageFileSize(evolvingImageFS.Length, evolvingImageFS)
        setNewImageAreaSize(evolvingImageFS.Length - headerBytes.Length, evolvingImageFS)

        'close off the stream
        evolvingImageFS.Close()
        evolvingImageFS.Dispose()

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

For anyone interested I have posted my solution. This works well for me but will probably need some tweaking for individual uses. This is also limited by the theoretical limits of bmp files being 16^8 bytes.